# Could not get desired output when using state varible in JSON

Tags: json, react-native

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    Button,
    AsyncStorage,
    Alert,
    Keyboard,
    ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';
import Color from '../constants/color';

class UserPage_1 extends Component {

    logoutFunction = () => {
        AsyncStorage.removeItem('user');
        Alert.alert("Sucessfully LoggedOut")
        this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginScreen');
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            UserId: '',
            Password: '',
            isLoading: true,
            CompanyName: '',
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Keyboard.dismiss();
        AsyncStorage.getItem('userid').then((value) => this.setState({ UserId: value }));
        AsyncStorage.getItem('password').then((value) => this.setState({ Password: value }));

        this.setState({
            UserId: this.state.UserId,
            Password: this.state.Password,

        })

        const { UserId } = this.state;
        const { Password } = this.state;

        fetch('http://<myserverip>/php/UserPage_1.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                user_id: UserId,
                password: Password,
            })
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {

                // If server response message same as Data Matched
                if (responseJson !== null) {
                    //Then open Profile activity and send user email to profile activity.
                    this.setState({
                        isLoading: false,
                        CompanyName: responseJson[0]['cmpny_name'],
                    })
                    console.log(responseJson);

                }
                else {
                    this.setState({ isLoading: false });
                    console.log(responseJson);
                }
            }).done();
    }
```

responseJson output is correct when I use the values directly 
output is: Array [Object {"cmpny_name": "k","cus_name": "k","id": "1","mob_no": "k","password": "k","user_id": "k",},]
But when I use state variable the responsejson output is like : Object {"password": "","user_id": "",}
couldn't find the reason why?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with PHP?

Comment: I use php at backend!

Comment: Sure, but the question seems to be about JS, not PHP. Tags should be what's directly relevant to the question.

Comment: Sry but what `values` is used directly? The code is a bit too long and I recommend to post a minimal example next time :)

Comment: okay will make note of that ! thanks

Comment: I passed username and password directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `AsyncStorage` returns a `Promise` object, you need to wait until data is fetched.

Make `logoutFunction` as an `async` function and wait until data removed from `AsyncStorage`

```
logoutFunction = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem('user');
    Alert.alert("Sucessfully LoggedOut")
    this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginScreen');
}
```

Changed your `componentDidMount` as below,

```
async componentDidMount() {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    try {
        const UserId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userid');
        const Password = await AsyncStorage.getItem('password');
        if (UserId !== null && Password !== null) {
            fetch('http://<myserverip>/php/UserPage_1.php', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    user_id: UserId,
                    password: Password,
                })
            }).then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    if (responseJson !== null) {
                        this.setState({
                            isLoading: false,
                            CompanyName: responseJson[0]['cmpny_name'],
                        })
                    }
                    else {
                        this.setState({
                            isLoading: false
                        });
                    }
                }).done();
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error retrieving data');
    }
}
```

Since I don't have full source code I was enabled to test this. Change this according to your requirements.
Feel free for doubts. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but this code actually uses the data(username and password from previous screen)  to fetch user details and display them.

Comment: then why do you want to get userId & password from ```AsyncStorage```?

Comment: Because the user id and password is entered in previous page(login page) from that page it redirect to this above mentioned page and AsyncStorage is used to create a local session

Comment: @KeerthieaaswarRamachandran it thinks the problem with storing userId & Password. if possible share your login code as well.

Comment: if I display the state variable in console.log the value passed is displaying correctly but when I give that to a const variable and pass that to php file the value is null

Comment: where you display state? I think it is better to share your code.